# Drink/eat off/from/in a cup/bowl/plate

Tags: word-choice, prepositions, food

Which combinations are you most likely to use? Do you drink *from* a cup? Eat something *in* a bowl?

I got into an argument with a Welsh English speaker over this. He insisted that he drinks and eats *off* a cup, bowl, and plate. He added that "from" would be OK, but not perfect. Me, I'm an American English speaker and I drink and eat *from* or *in* a cup or bowl, and I eat *off* a plate.

Comment: Can you -eat- from a cup?

Comment: Of course you can :)

Answer (score 2):

I would say the preposition used is determined by the position of the food/drink.

Your cereal is *in* a bowl, so you eat it *out of* or *from* the bowl. Similarly your coffee is *in* a mug so you drink it *out of* or *from* the mug.

Your meal is on a plate, so you eat it *off [of]* or *from* the plate.

*From* works in both *on* or *in* situations because it is a preposition that indicates the source or origin of something.

*Off [of]* only works for *on* situations because it is the opposite. Similarly for *in* and *out of*.

Comment: How about this rule of thumb: If you tip the container, and the food slides *off* it, then you eat *off* it. Otherwise, it's *from*.

Comment: @JeffSahol: Yeah, that pretty much covers it.

Comment: Thank goodness that's codified now. One less thing to worry about.

Comment: This seems logical to us English speakers, but in French you drink _in_ a cup.

Answer (score 0):

I’m English and I drink *out of* or *from* a cup, eat *off* a plate and *out of* a bowl. Does this Welsh English speaker speak Welsh? If so, he may be letting Welsh influence his English.